# AVPlayerItemFailedToPlayToEndTimeNotification be posted when and for what

Tags: swift, audio, avplayer, notice, avplayeritem

Recently, I am use AVPlayer to play some audio made by someone else.

When I look the AVPlayerItem, I see the **AVPlayerItemFailedToPlayToEndTimeNotification** and **AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification**,

I am confused by failedToPlayEnd, who can tell me what is the failedToPlayEnd.

Very thanks. You may help me.

Comment: same as no reply,your answer is no any means.

Comment: If the track is being streamed and encounters an error you'll get this. Also if the track has been corrupted and only plays partway through you'll get it.